# Browserify.js in Production

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

Just a quick question about Browserify.js, is it just a tool for your development environment or is it something that runs with the client on a live web site?  If you can use it in production, would you have to have Node running on you web server?  I know that it is used for packaging up js modules but was curious if you just pack up these modules loacally and then transfer that bundle.js file to production.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for Stack Overflow but what you should do is serve up the bundle generated from Browserify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a tool for development. You use it to create your production js code. You do not need to run browserify on the server hosting the webpage. The js output file does not depend on node.